# LoadRunner HTML Mode Scripts - Detailed Individual Response Times

Tags: loadrunner

We have recorded Load Runner scripts for a web page using HTML mode and the script looks as below. In EXTRARES section; we have several JS/CSS & Image files (>100 requests) that are part of web page. This page is taking long time and we would like to identify which of the 100+ requests included in EXTRARES are causing for high response time. We are not able to find a way to get the response time of each request included in EXTRARES from LoadRunner. Is there anyway we can get granular details of how long each request in EXTRARES is taking?

```
web_url("hostname.com", 
        "URL=http://hostname.com", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        EXTRARES, 
        "Url=/styles/abc1.css", "Referer=http://hostname.com", ENDITEM, 
        "Url=/styles/abc2.css", "Referer=http://hostname.com", ENDITEM, 
LAST);
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to find information on how to get more diagnostics of individual breakdown of each request's response time using Web Page Diagnostics graph available in Load Runner. My understanding is this provide only a maximum of 10% data sampling of total data available. How is this data sampling done by Load Runner, is the data taken for specific interval of time during the test? If we need to troubleshoot slow response times, is 10% data sampling enough to drill down or is there a way to capture all data sampling for web page breakdown?

Answer (score 1):

Record in URL mode and turn on automatic transactions for each request.  You will likely need to adjust the first value for each request action to normalize some of the request labels to be used for automatic transactions, for you may have some items requested multiple times resulting in labels such as "Foo," "Foo_1," "Foo_2..." as the same file is re-requested multiple times (such as a common stylesheet across pages).  in such a case simply normalize the labels, unless you really want to understand what happens for a particular page vs a particular request.